# Render a file along with username into the url after form was submitted using express

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, ejs

I have a nodeJS application which takes user information from a form and saves to a mongoDB database using mongoose.

```
example:
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    newUser.save()
}
```

I've seen other websites which updates the url after the form is submitted with what I guess is a query string of the user and adds to the end of the url.

```
Example: http://stackoverflow.com/profile/Jon%Doe
```

Not sure how to update a url with user information after the form was submitted. 
I tried to render a file:

```
router.req('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('profile' + username) //username is a variable of the user
}
```

but that only looks for a url with a username. Thinking I have to update the ejs template files with the username somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the URL after a form post, you would use `res.redirect()` to redirect the browser to a new URL.  The browser will then request that new url and you would need to have a route for that new URL in order to return the desired page content.

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    // other code here to process form data
    newUser.save(..., function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.sendStatus(500);
        } else {
            // build new URL here
            res.redirect(newURL);
        }
    });
}
```

If you then want to display the username in the page that you redirect to, you would use an EJS template that has a place in it for the user name and you would fetch the username from wherever you put it in the URL and feed that to the `res.render()` for the template so that EJS would insert the user name in the proper place.

If you're doing some kind of login, then you may want to do the whole process differently.  You may want to create a user session object (probably with `express-session`) on the server and keep the username in there so then anytime you want to render a page, the username can be fetched from the server-side session object rather than putting it in the URL.  This is probably a bit more foolproof.

Comment: I understand how to get the params from the url into the webpage.. but after submitting the form, how do I get the username appended to the end of the newUrl.. so it would be localhost:3000/newUrl/john after that I would get john and use EJS and fetch the username "john" into the page.  res.redirect(newUrl) just goes to the new url. I need to have the username in the url as well.   After I figure this out, I want to look into sessions also.

Comment: @BradVanderbush - please reread my answer. You construct the new url and use `res.redirect()` for the response.  I think its all in the answer.  If you don't understand something in the answer, then ask a more specific question about what you don't understand.

Comment: @BradVanderbush - Instead of `res.render()`, you construct the new URL with the name in it and use `res.redirect(newURL)`.  Then, create a route that handles the new URL.  When the browser gets the redirect, it will then request the new URL and your server will get a request for the new URL and you can then render the page in that request handler with the name in it.

Comment: You're correct, I was missing the whole point, I was thinking res.redirect()  had to have a legit working url.

Comment: @BradVanderbush - `res.redirect()` DOES need a legit working URL. You call `res.redirect(url)`.  The browser gets the redirect response and then requests that new URL.  Your server has to then serve the page from that new url.  This is a good thing.  If a URL is showing in the browser, your server better know what to do with it anyway - that's how things work in the browser.

Comment: router.get('/:name', (req, res) =>{
 res.render('form', {person: req.params.name})
});
router.post('/login', (req, res) =>{
 return res.status(200).send({
  result: 'redirect', 
  url:'/concat:hey',
 })
});            This works.. I was using AJAX and that was my problem.

Comment: @BradVanderbush - I don't know what that last comment means, but `router.get('/:name', ...)` matches every single top level URL including things like `/login` so that's probably not what you want.  I'd suggest something like `router.get('/user/:name', ...)`.

Comment: Plus, if you want the browser to redirect to another URL, then do `res.redirect(newURL)` instead of `res.send(...)`.  Maybe you need to go read the doc for `res.redirect()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174980/discussion-between-brad-vanderbush-and-jfriend00).